# php script not rendering

Tags: php, xampp

so i worked on a php project on my localhost and every thing was ok but now, every php file im trying to open just downloads itself (Chrome) or asks if i want to download it (Firefox). i tried to go back to as basic as possible and came out with this index.php file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

but the only way i can open it without downloading itself is if im changing it to .html file and than i just don't see the hello world. i already re-installed xampp. i can go to phpmyadmin on my local (if it helps) and thats unfortunately all te useful information i can come up with...any help please?

Comment: Is the file in the server root directory and you call it over the server which is turned on?

Comment: Use Chrome's webinspector (f12) to see the response headers. Can you post them?

Comment: You cant open php files via file:// use start xampp and open go to localhost.

Comment: How you access your file ? if you drag & drop on FF you wouldnt see anything, in chrome you can see the whole php code(not render). If you put it under htdocs folder (xampp) then you access it via url `http://localhost/pathToYourTargetFile`. So, if you access it using last method and you prompt to download there must be something wrong. And of course if you double click on the php file its should be open the file in code editor. Of course if your app recognizing *.php file.

Comment: thanks for the help...didnt know i cant render php unless its threw the localhost/pathToFile

Comment: Look root. Problem is root.

Comment: Notice, php is server side code not a client side code. So *.php going under server public directory and accessible via url.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your httpd.conf has properly configured php module. And, you have enabled support for php files.